# SF Story identification 1960s story Analog magazine aliens conquer Earth by making everyone fall asleep

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi

I'm trying to recall an SF story that was serialized in Analog magazine in the 1960s. Aliens invaded Earth by using a gas that made almost everyone fall asleep. A few individuals were either immune or in a protected environment. One of these was a man who had lost one or both legs. Normally he used robotic legs, but for some reason they were taken away. He may have been in a prison. Together, the few humans left awake somehow defeat the invasion.

I'm not sure if this story was ever published in book form. I read in Analog.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be wonderful. Thanks!

Comment: Possibly very similar to [Old science fiction book about an alien invasion thwarted by robot-made ghosts](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4065/30482) [keywords: Grandpa ↔ “Gremper”] (but its answer has not been accepted).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Sleeping Planet](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/20625439-sleeping-planet)
by William R Burkett

Serialized in *Analog*, 1964, July, August, and September.

> *Science Fiction Encyclopedia* described this as a “hard-edged” tale of the 24th-century conquest of Earth by an alien empire the humans had judged too stupid to pull off such a coup. Only a handful of humans escaped the effects of a mutated narcoleptic drug that put humanity into protracted hibernation. The battle to liberate Earth is fought by those few...

[image]

Comment: That's it, perfect! Thank you so much. And the cover, too!